# How can get the current region inside the 'hook_preprocess_block'?

Tags: theming, blocks

How can I get the current region name inside the `hook_preprocess_block()`?
I tried the following code, but it seems something is wrong.

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['elements']['#region'] == "nav") {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'SomeStyle';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation for [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.6.x), 
`$variables['elements']['#block']` is available, and it contains the [Block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Entity%21Block.php/class/Block/8.4.x) object. With that, you can get the region to which the block is assigned with [`Block::getRegion()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Entity%21Block.php/function/Block%3A%3AgetRegion/8.4.x).

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#block']) && $variables['elements']['#block']->getRegion() == 'nav') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'SomeStyle';
  }
}
```

That is slightly different from Drupal 7, where `hook_preprocess_block()` would get the region assigned to the block from `$variables['block']->region`, or from `$variables['elements']['#block']->region`. See [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x) (Drupal 7).

```
  $block_counter = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  $variables['block'] = $variables['elements']['#block'];
  // All blocks get an independent counter for each region.
  if (!isset($block_counter[$variables['block']->region])) {
    $block_counter[$variables['block']->region] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you a lot for your help and attention, I tested your code in drupal 8, It seems that something should be wrong because howsoever I try I can't get any result

Comment: Did you try the 1st code of this answer, the one for D8? instead of `$variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'SomeStyle';` put `drupal_set_message('it works');` for testing purposes to see if the code it's working or not.

Comment: @No Sssweat: I test your idea about using of `drupal_set_message('it works');` but nothing is showed up.

Comment: remove the if statement, do you get anything if you do `dpm($variables['elements']['#block']);` ?

Comment: There is no `$variables['elements']['#block']`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something has changed and `variables['elements']['#block']` is not available anymore.

Here is what worked

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = entity_load('block', $variables['elements']['#id']);
  $region = $block->getRegion();
  if ($region == 'nav') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'SomeStyle';
  }
}
```